Why does model training stops at the first epoch (epoch 0)?
I'm training models using PyTorch Lightning. I built a loop to train one model at a time, but only the first model goes "far", the other two are always stopping at the first epoch. Very strange, as my early stopping is for 3 epochs.
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
from torch import nn
from torch.optim import Adam
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy
from torchvision import models


def create_model(architecture):
    if architecture == "efficientnet_b0":
        model = models.efficientnet_b0(weights="DEFAULT")
        num_features = model.classifier[1].in_features
        model.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(num_features, 2)
    elif architecture == "mobilenet_v2":
        model = models.mobilenet_v2(weights="DEFAULT")
        model.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(model.last_channel, 2)
    elif architecture == "mobilenet_v3_large":
        model = models.mobilenet_v3_large(weights="DEFAULT")
        model.classifier[3] = nn.Linear(1280, 2)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown architecture: {architecture}")
    return model


class BaseModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, architecture):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = create_model(architecture)
        self.architecture = architecture
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def on_save_checkpoint(self, checkpoint):
        checkpoint["architecture"] = self.architecture

    @classmethod
    def load_from_checkpoint(cls, checkpoint_path):
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path)
        model = cls(checkpoint["architecture"])
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["state_dict"])
        return model

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        acc = accuracy(preds, labels, task="binary")
        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        self.log("train_acc", acc, on_step=True, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        acc = accuracy(preds, labels, task="binary")
        self.log("val_loss", loss)
        self.log("val_acc", acc, on_step=True, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        acc = accuracy(preds, labels, task="binary")
        self.log("test_loss", loss)
        self.log("test_acc", acc, on_step=True, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)


early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss", patience=3, verbose=False, mode="min"
)


def train_model(train_loader, val_loader, test_loader, num_epochs, device):
    models = [
        BaseModel("efficientnet_b0"),
        BaseModel("mobilenet_v2"),
        BaseModel("mobilenet_v3_large"),
    ]

    for model in models:
        model = model.to(device)
        logger = TensorBoardLogger("lightning_logs", name=model.architecture)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(
            max_epochs=num_epochs,
            callbacks=[early_stop_callback],
            accelerator="gpu",
            devices=1,
            logger=logger,
        )
        trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
        trainer.test(model, test_loader)

ERROR:
GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
You are using a CUDA device ('NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti') that has Tensor Cores. To properly utilize them, you should set `torch.set_float32_matmul_precision('medium' | 'high')` which will trade-off precision for performance. For more details, read https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_float32_matmul_precision.html#torch.set_float32_matmul_precision
Missing logger folder: lightning_logs\efficientnet_b0
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name      | Type             | Params
-----------------------------------------------
0 | model     | EfficientNet     | 4.0 M 
1 | criterion | CrossEntropyLoss | 0     
-----------------------------------------------
4.0 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
4.0 M     Total params
16.040    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking: |                                                                                                                                   | 0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]C:\Users\felipe\.conda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\connectors\data_connector.py:441: The 'val_dataloader' does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` to `num_workers=31` in the `DataLoader` to improve performance.
C:\Users\felipe\.conda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\connectors\data_connector.py:441: The 'train_dataloader' does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` to `num_workers=31` in the `DataLoader` to improve performance.
Epoch 7: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 463/463 [04:14<00:00,  1.82it/s, v_num=0] 
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]                                                                                                                                   
C:\Users\felipe\.conda\envs\pytorch\Lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\connectors\data_connector.py:441: The 'test_dataloader' does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` to `num_workers=31` in the `DataLoader` to improve performance.
Testing DataLoader 0: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:58<00:00,  1.71it/s] 
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Test metric        ┃       DataLoader 0        ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│      test_acc_epoch       │    0.9996848702430725     │
│         test_loss         │   0.0006146501400507987   │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
Missing logger folder: lightning_logs\mobilenet_v2
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name      | Type             | Params
-----------------------------------------------
0 | model     | MobileNetV2      | 2.2 M
1 | criterion | CrossEntropyLoss | 0
-----------------------------------------------
2.2 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
2.2 M     Total params
8.906     Total estimated model params size (MB)
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 463/463 [04:18<00:00,  1.79it/s, v_num=0] 
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]                                                                                                                                   
Testing DataLoader 0: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:46<00:00,  2.16it/s] 
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Test metric        ┃       DataLoader 0        ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│      test_acc_epoch       │     0.994957447052002     │
│         test_loss         │    0.0266144797205925     │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
GPU available: True (cuda), used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
Missing logger folder: lightning_logs\mobilenet_v3_large
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name      | Type             | Params
-----------------------------------------------
0 | model     | MobileNetV3      | 4.2 M
1 | criterion | CrossEntropyLoss | 0
-----------------------------------------------
4.2 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
4.2 M     Total params
16.818    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 463/463 [04:15<00:00,  1.81it/s, v_num=0] 
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
Testing DataLoader 0: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:49<00:00,  2.01it/s]
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Test metric        ┃       DataLoader 0        ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│      test_acc_epoch       │     0.946107804775238     │
│         test_loss         │    0.31665417551994324    │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘

I tried running 1 at a time manually and it worked correctly, but I would like to automate this process. I expected the models to train normally.

Can you show more code? Where and how you call train_model method.
Consider default value for epochs used by the Trainer is 'trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=1000)', try by default if this change, and if continue to show only one epoch check if the progress bar setting is correct

@Degik Of course, here is the code that calls the train_model method
`
import torch
from data.data import load_data
from scripts.train import train_model
from utils.hyperparameters import EPOCHS
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
data_path = ""
train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = load_data(data_path)
train_model(train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset, EPOCHS, device)
`

Have you tried to do what I told you?
From this code, I can't see any problem.
Try and retry with different params, my doubt was you are using a tool like tqdm bad for the progress bar

@Degik Yes, I managed to discover the error. Thank you for your help.

The early stop method must be inside the for loop to reset its values, cleaning up the dirt from the previous model. The other models were stopping training in the first epoch, as the early stopping was not being restarted.
